# Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Greenwich.RC2

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am working under Verizon firewall restriction and when i install below netflix dependency its showing compile time errors like below what is problem?,Do i have to add additional information can some one help me please?

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RC2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Attachment

[image]

Comment: Is it version problem or something?

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses the versioning syntax `RC` to indicate a Release Candidate. Release candidates requires a milestone repository segment in your pom.xml:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository> 
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id> 
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name> 
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-repository#milestones-candidates) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/21/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc2-is-now-available). As Spring Greenwich Release is available since [January 23, 2019](https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/23/spring-cloud-greenwich-release-is-now-available), you might want to check if your dependencies are available in the release version.

Answer (score 0):

Add a global property for spring-cloud version.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

inject it in dependency management

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Then add the repositories

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```